# Php MySQL Category Result

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm looking for the best method to display a category list in Android. What I need is a list in the app of all the categories an item falls under, then if they select that category, it would display all the items under that category.

I'm wondering how I can make this most easily, I'm not sure which one of two options is easiest, or possible. I was thinking that I could have a column in my table and the column would be named "category" for example. I would fill in the category for each row such as "food, equipment, tools" etc, but I want only the category to show up and then if selected the items within that category.

Or.

Would it be easier to make a column for each category and select it as a "true" "false" sort of way. Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fill the **first list** with data from mysql

```
select category from table group by category;
```

after click on one category-name, fill the **sub-list** with data from the ItemClick category-name.

```
....
Object ox = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
....
"select * from table where category="+ox.toString()+'"';
```

**memo: this is only the act, is not the code**

Comment: Now, if i have 40 things in my database with the category "food" would "food" show up 40 times?

Comment: Okay, I understand it now. I'm getting force close on my app but I'm sure it's in the app not the php. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you are satisfied with the answer. please mark it as correct answer